# How to sort 'Map' values in Scala against multiple factors?

Tags: java, scala, maps, scala-collections

I have a Map (datatype) with the following data structure:

```
var timePassedCamerasetB = mutable.Map.empty[String, Time];
```

It contains a String and a 'Time' object. The 'Time' object is made up from my own class. Below you can see what it consists of:

```
case class Time(daysSinceEpoch: Int, hours: Int, minutes: Int, seconds: Double)
```

I have saved all my data into this 'Map' variable. But there is one problem: I want to sort the values in this 'Map' variable based on multiple things, but I can't find any way to make it work.

For example. I have stored the following data within this map:

```
PP-33-XX -> Time(18492,3,7,0.0)
BA-12-PW -> Time(18492,9,0,40.0)
MM-11-OW -> Time(18492,3,7,16.0)
NX-66-PP -> Time(18492,3,6,30.0)
LA-53-NY -> Time(18492,9,0,56.0)
```

I want to sort the values in order (earliest time to latest time). This includes comparing multiple factors. First compare each daysSinceEpoch, then hours, minutes and seconds.

I want to transform the map into the following down below:

```
NX-66-PP -> Time(18492,3,6,30.0)
PP-33-XX -> Time(18492,3,7,0.0)
MM-11-OW -> Time(18492,3,7,16.0)
BA-12-PW -> Time(18492,9,0,40.0)
LA-53-NY -> Time(18492,9,0,56.0)
```

Does anyone know of an efficient way to do this? Unfortunately I can't..

Comment: `Maps` are unordered collections by nature, why do you care about the order? Anyways, you probably will end up using a sequence like a `List` and then use `orderBy`

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! I do understand that. The order is very important to me for educational reasons. I get your thinking, but could you maybe explain this through code? Maybe I'll understand it better then. The end goal is to keep the sorted values ​​in a 'Map' datatype (as pictured above) again. @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez

Comment: I believe jwvh's answer goes in the direction you are looking for. In general, `Map`s don't have ordering, but specific implementations can either preserve insertion order (like `ListMap`s or `LinkedHashMap`s) or maintain ordering by key (like `TreeSet`s). I'm not aware of `Map` implementations in the standard library that maintain ordering by value.

Comment: Hi @Brian, today you posted a python question on how to count the occurrence of certain climate words in a dataframe column. I was working on your question but the question got deleted. However, I found a solution that might help you. Do `pattern = "|".join(list_of_words)`. Then use `df.Clean_text.str.count(pattern)`. This should give you what you were looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like a `ListMap` is what you want.

From the [ScalaDocs page](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/ListMap.html): *"Entries are stored internally in reversed insertion order, which means the newest key is at the head of the list."*

So to transit from the current `Map` to a `ListMap`:

```
import scala.collection.immutable.ListMap

val newMap: ListMap[String,Time] = 
  oldMap.toList.sortBy{
    case (_, Time(d,h,m,s)) => (d,h,m,s)
  }.foldLeft(ListMap[String,Time]())(_+_)
```

testing:

```
newMap.head //res0: (NX-66-PP,Time(18492,3,6,30.0))
newMap.last //res1: (LA-53-NY,Time(18492,9,0,56.0))
newMap("MM-11-OW")    //res2: Time(18492,3,7,16.0)
```

Answer (score 3):

As Luis commented, Maps, specifically `mutable.Map` aren't designed to hold ordered values. If you could go with a List it can be easily sorted like this:

```
timePassedCamerasetB
    .toList
    .sortBy {
      case (_, time) => (time.daysSinceEpoch, time.hours, time.minutes, time.seconds)
    }
```

This expression has to be assigned to new value